# How to unwind nested object arrays in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have some data with an array of objects which contains another array. I am trying to unwind the **courses** array then the **requirements** array to match subjects then group everything back together.

So far I can work fine with the **courses** array. But I just can't get around doing the same thing for the second array  **requirements**.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "provider name",
    "courses": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "course name",
        "requirements": [
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          },
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

First I unwind both arrays

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$courses',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$courses.requirements',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
```

How I group the first array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      root: { $mergeObjects: '$$ROOT' },
      courses: { $push: '$courses' }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: ['$root', '$$ROOT'],
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { root: 0 }
  },
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "provider name",
    "courses": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "course name",
        "requirements": [
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          },
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I get

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "provider name",
    "courses": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "course name",
        "requirements": [
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          },
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "course name",
        "requirements": [
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          },
          {
            "subjects": [
              "SubjectA::B",
              "SubjectB::B",
              "SubjectC::B"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reconstruct tour arrays by below stages,

- `$group` by `_id` and `courses._id` and get first `name` and course first name, and construct the `requirements` array
- `$group` by only `_id` and get first `name` and reconstruct `courses` array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        cId: "$courses._id"
      },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      course_name: { $first: "$courses.name" },
      requirements: { $push: "$courses.requirements" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      courses: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id.cId",
          name: "$course_name",
          requirements: "$requirements"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PVk6hYPNR5U)

Comment: Great, that really helped. So if I run this pipeline on thousands of records would that involve a high cost on the database?

Comment: what you mean by *high cost*? if you are talking about performance its ok if you have more documents in root, but it will affect if you have more nested documents.

Comment: Yes, performance, my expectations after the first few match stages will end up with less than a hundred for each courses array and around 2 to 3 in the requirements array. would this approach be okay performance-wise or it is not recommended.

Comment: it will affect performance issue but, can you explain and share what match are you doing before group stage. so i will share another query without unwind and group stage. so after that you can compare both queries performance.

Comment: Sure, I have a few hundred documents that I am filtering called providers.
Each one contains a courses array with a few up to 1000 elements.
each course contains a requirement array.
So at first, I am filtering the providers' main documents say I would get a 100 out of them
then I am filtering them again according to some fields in courses array.
that would lead me to have around 50 providers or less and each one has courses array with a couple of hundred in them. my Other option was to use $function and for each course pass the requirement array and work out javascript myself to filter,

Comment: i can understand but can you share what filtering are you doing before $group stage, can you add that in playground and share me new link.

Comment: okay currently I don't have much i just filter by name location and so on I will come back and share all the pipeline once I have a full version to review the performance. But thanks any way for the help